# Go handling websockets and HTTP with the same handler

Tags: http, go, websocket

Been scouring for a while but couldn't find anything that directly answers this.

Can Go handle WS connections and HTTP connections using the same handler?

In short, I'd like to replicate something like SignalR

Comment: How do you expect to "degrade" from a websocket to http on the server? Either the client is requesting a websocket, or it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I realised just after I posted and hadn't edited it in time.  I am aware of tools client side to determine browser capabilities.  I've edited my question to be specific to the server side.

Comment: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket seems to suggest the answer is "yes".  The `Upgrader.Upgrade()` will return `nil` error if it can upgrade the protocol to websockets, so you can check for that condition.

Comment: I also found this -http://talks.golang.org/2012/chat.slide#30 - I just didn't want to have duplicate handlers for WS and HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the gorilla/websocket package supports upgrade from HTTP to WebSocket in a request handler. See the example at the [beginning of the package documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket). The function `handler` is a standard HTTP request handler. The call to `upgrader.Upgrade` switches the connection to the  WebSocket protocol.

The x/net/websocket package requires a separate handler. There are [other reasons](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages) why you probably don't want to use the x/net/websocket package.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up needing to filter the request myself before passing it to `upgrader.upgrade` method. Because `upgrader.upgrade`, upon failing to upgrade the request, write 'Bad request' response to it. Something that will render my HTML as plain text with additional 'Bad request' text in the beginning.

So this is what I do at the top of the `handler`:

```golang
func singleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrade := false
    for _, header := range r.Header["Upgrade"] {
        if header == "websocket" {
            upgrade = true
            break
        }
    }

    if upgrade == false {
        if r.Method != "GET" {
            http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        chatTemplate.Execute(w, listenAddr)
        return
    }

    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Upgrade err:", err)
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is an example repo: https://github.com/siriusdely/gochat. Based on Andrew Gerrand's talk: code that grows with grace https://talks.golang.org/2012/chat.slide#44.